# Anallytic geometry problem

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, analytic-geometry, rectangles

We are given an rectangle **ABCD**. **M** and **N** are the middles of **AC** and **BD**. Prove that 
$$\overrightarrow{MN}=\frac{1}{2}(\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{CD})=\frac{1}{2}(\overrightarrow{AD}+\overrightarrow{CB})$$

Comment: No, you should first show your work on the problem to get a favourable response.

Comment: Problem is I have no idea where to start so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The hint.

All rectangle is a parallelogram.

Prove that $\vec{MN}=\vec{0}$, $\vec{AB}+\vec{CD}=\vec{0}$ and $\vec{AD}+\vec{CB}=\vec{0}$.